# Send multiple attachments with an email PHP

Tags: php, html

I want to send multiple attachments with an email. The below is my code

```
$file = 'C:/Users/pdf/Testing.pdf';

$mailto = 'mail@mail.com';
$subject = 'Subject';
$message = 'My message';

$content = file_get_contents($file);
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
```

// I can give $content to only one file and I have to give multiple pdf files here

```
// a random hash will be necessary to send mixed content
$separator = md5(time());

// carriage return type (RFC)
$eol = PHP_EOL;

// main header (multipart mandatory)
$headers = "From: name <test@test.com>" . $eol;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . $eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $separator . "\"" . $eol;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit" . $eol;
$headers .= "This is a MIME encoded message." . $eol;

// message
$body = "--" . $separator . $eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"" . $eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . $eol;
$body .= $message . $eol;

// attachment
$body .= "--" . $separator . $eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . $filename . "\"" . $eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $eol;
$body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment" . $eol;
$body .= $content . $eol;
$body .= "--" . $separator . "--";

//SEND Mail
if (mail($mailto, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
    echo "mail send ... OK"; // or use booleans here
} else {
    echo "mail send ... ERROR!";
    print_r( error_get_last() );
}
```

This code send me only one files as an attachment and I have to send the other file as well.

```
$file2 = 'C:/Users/pdf/sample1.pdf'; // The path for 2nd pdf file
```

Comment: Maybe you can try to put them in an array? You could try that! Like this: `$content = [file_get_contents($file), file_get_contents($file1)]`

Comment: md5 hash? reason for this?

Comment: @IsaacI got his code from SO community answers and am trying to work on this code

Comment: Personally I'd leave this work to a tried-and-tested mailing library. Otherwise you have to add just another message part and there are only a couple of dozens RFCs to adhere to, though.

Answer (score 2):

Please try below code. You can create attachment array like

```
$attachement = array();
$attachement['data'][0] = 'pdfdata' // Pass PDF content with  base64_encode
$attachement['data'][1] = 'tpPdfdata';

$attachement['name'][0] = 'sample1.pdf';
$attachement['name'][1] = 'sample2.pdf';
enter code here

<?php
    public function send($to, $from, $subject, $message, 
        $cc, $attachement='') {        

        $mail_header = "From: $from\n";
        if (isset($cc)) {
            $mail_header .= "Cc:$cc\n";
        }        

        $mail_header.= "Reply-To: noreply@demo.com\n";
        $mail_header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0";

        // boundary 
        $semi_rand = md5(time());
        $boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

        // headers for attachment 
        $mail_header .= "\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$boundary}\"";

        // multipart boundary 
        $message = "--{$boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n" .
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n";

        // preparing attachments
        if (count($attachement) > 0) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($attachement); $i++) {
                $message .= "--{$boundary}\n";
                $data = $attachement['data'][$i];
                $message .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . $attachement['name'][$i] . "\"\n" .
                    //"Content-Description: ".basename($files[$i])."\n" .
                    "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"" . $attachement['name'][$i] . "\"; size=" . filesize($attachement['name'][$i]) . ";\n" .
                    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
            }
        }
        $message .= "--{$boundary}--";
        return mail($to, $subject, $message, $mail_header);
    }
?>
```

If you using normal mail function you can achieve using above code.You can pass argument like to, from, subject,attachment etc... Please try. Thank you

Comment: I just tried your code but it didn't worked out. I have declared  $file1 = 'C:/Users/pdf/Test.pdf'; $file2 = 'C:/Users/pdf/Test1.pdf'; $attachement['data'][0] = chunk_split(base64_encode($file2)); 
$attachement['data'][1] = chunk_split(base64_encode($file1));

Comment: @John:What you getting error? please share error so i will help you

Comment: @Dipti yes i also tried to use this i am not getting any error other than no email gets send, what am i missing

Comment: Hi @Gcobza Have you configure send email settings in server leavel. If you are using Xampp then need to set in PHP.ini for smtp/send email settings